# How to check if m3u8 live stream is alive?

Tags: java, php, streaming, video-streaming, m3u8

I can get the JSON sent by the streaming link, and get the mime type out of it, but this is not enough. I actually want to check if the m3u8 link is actually streaming. JSON is like this:

```
"description": "Adaptive",
    "url": "http://media1-lh.maihd.net/i/English_1@123035/master.m3u8",
    "mimetype": "application/vnd.apple.mpegURL"
```

I have been searching for a tool, or some code, preferably in Java or PHP, which could check the m3u8 link every few minutes to make sure the links is actually streaming. So far I have not been able to find any solution to this so asking it here if someone could help.

Answer (score 0):

The the stream is live, new segments will be added to the end of the m3u8 file every few seconds. Check to see if the contents of the m3u8 have changed.

Comment: From segments you mean the '.m3u8?sd\u003d10\u0026rebase\u003don' part?

Comment: No. That is probably some sort of access token. I mean the contents of the m3u8 file.

Answer (score 0):

try many times

```
curl http://media1-lh.maihd.net/i/English_1@123035/master.m3u8
```

Check the contents of the m3u8 have changed.